# df reports zero used space

Tags: azure, nfs, df

On a VM in azure we mount some blob storage via NFS, which generally works good. I now found though, that `df` reports wrong values for usage of the NFS storage:

```
root@myVM:~# df -h /mnt/blob/
Filesystem                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
storagename.blob.core.windows.net:/storagename/data  5.0P     0  5.0P   0% /mnt/blob
```

As you can see, it looks like we don't have any data in `/mnt/blob`, which is wrong. We stored lots of files there.
We are running current **Debian 11.6** there and used these mount options:

```
storagename.blob.core.windows.net:/storagename/data /mnt/blob nfs nfsvers=3,nolock,proto=tcp 0 0
```

Is this

- related to Azure (mounting blob)
- related to huge FS (several petabyte)
- maybe network related (tcp -> firewall?)

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Try `df -k` to see it in kilobytes. You have 5 petabytes, so if you have used 5TB this will not be visible with `-h`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but still no success. The columns for "Used" as well as "Use%" show 0 (0%), even in Kilobyte.